# firefox positioning cuts page short

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am using css which seems to be cutting my page short in firefox but looks fine in Chrome.
I am not sure how to solve this problem, as I cannot change all position:relative elements to absolute.

The .content class seems to be the place where all the action is happening.

```
.content {
    display:block;
    position:absolute; /*originally relative*/
    background-color: #678238;
    min-height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    line-height: 40px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:0;
}
```

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/55922jjs/

live version (outdated slightly):
http://bitbear.me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)